# Problems Building Application as Release in Visual Studio 2008 - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build, release, winapi

I'm having a little trouble building my application as Release in Visual Studio 2008.  It builds fine without any errors or warning as Debug.  The application is primarily Win32 with a little MFC and ATL mixed in here and there.  Most of the projects in the solution generate a LIB and DLL.

This is one of the errors I am getting:

> fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

My application *is* a multithreaded DLL, so the `/MD` needs to stay.  The only Windows includes are these:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include "WMIQuery.h"
#include "SerialPort.h"
```

The other error is this:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'WMIQuery.h': No such file or directory

This one really doesn't make sense to me because, the environment has no problem finding this file building for Debug.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  If any additional information is needed, just say so, and I'll post.  Thanks.

Comment: Release and debug use different environments, so being able to find a header in debug means nothing with regards to finding it in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project property changes you've made to get it to build in the Debug configuration are not automatically applied to the Release configuration as well.  Note the "Configuration" combo in the upper left corner of the dialog.  Altered property values are shown in bold type.

If you cannot remember what changes you've made then open the .vcproj file in a text editor like Notepad.exe.  The settings that were changed from their default value are listed in the Debug|Win32 configuration section.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is most likely a mismatch in your project settings. Since you require /MD, check your project configuration properties for release, under the 'General' heading. There should be an item "Use of MFC". This should be set to "Use MFC in a Shared DLL".

The second error is probably due to a mismatch in include paths between the two configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your environment variables.  I believe it uses separate values for debugging and releasing.